# Large quantities of API requests on a Laravel RESTful service

Tags: php, laravel, api

So I have an app that does API call every minute or so to update local db on the app.

I don't know about scalability in this scenario, but let's say I have 100 users, so that makes it 100 api calls a minute or so.

How bad is this?

Is there a way to mock hundreds of api calls?

Comment: The app is polling your server for keeping its local db updated. Instead, I would send push notifications when any sensitive data changed in the server

Comment: That sounds better, I'll look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you explained above won't be bad at all, even when performed in a small server, assuming the call you are making is relatively short and does not use lots of memory in the server. This could be more efficient if you spin up more workers threads in your server.

Laravel's [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#supervisor-configuration) explains a little more.

Alternatively, you could use a well-known Java framework called JMeter to test your API calls in any scenarios you may want.

For more visit their [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/).

I hope this helps!